# One click GPU passthrough to VM in Gnome-Boxes?

Tags: 20.04, qemu, gnome-boxes, kvm-virtualization

[Felipe Borges](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRjY2plEymQ), Gnome Developer, spoke last year about new feature in gnome-boxes that allow simple PCI GPU passthrough to VM.

However, I can't find any information on the gnome documentation or examples of someone using the new GPU passthrough feature of Boxes. Seems like there would be strong demand for it. Is there a good simple 2021 guide I am missing?

I have a laptop with hybrid graphics Nvidia and need Windows VM for Fusion360.

I pass the gnome-boxes --checks for virtualization

I right click of gnome-boxes to launch selecting "with dedicated GPU"

My VM starts no problem, but Nvidia driver tool doesn't see the card.

Do I need to mess with grub to set kernel flags or go into virt-manager to make Boxes work with passthrough in my scenario or should it work out of the box?